# What is the best way to store a large set of single-column data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

- I have a massive list of strings in a text file, the file is about 100gb uncompressed.
- Each line of the text file is a single word (rougly 50 characters long), no spaces or punctuation.
- The table will be created and populated from this text file once, further updates to the table will not be necessary and if it helps the table can become read only.

The use-case is a function which would look something like this:

```
/**
 * Search the table and return true if the word exists, false if not.
 * /
wordExists(wordToCheck: string): boolean {}
```

I'm looking for advice here on what would be the best way to store the data to ensure that lookups are as fast and efficient as possible.

I'm not sure if breaking the word up into parts to try and assist in indexing it would help or not, I'm also not sure if it will help to partition this list.

Anyone have any advice for me?

Answer (score 0):

100GB is fairly long, and assuming each word averages 50 characters in length, this means that roughly a single column would have 2 billion words/records in it.  This is not so large that it is beyond the capability of Postgres.

I suggest creating and populating your table, and then adding a *hash index*:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable USING HASH (text_col);
```

Now any query against this table should be able to use the index for very rapid lookup.  For example, to see if a word exists, use:

```sql
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable WHERE text_col = 'meatballs');
```

If you run the explain plan, you should see the hash index being used with a fast lookup time.